# alamofire throws "expected declaration" error

Tags: swift, http-post, alamofire

I downloaded the latest versions of xcode and alamofire to create a simple app... unfortunately it seems impossible to send out a request !

Every time I try to build the project, xcode sends me a "expected declaration" error which I don't understand.

Any ideas ? I googled for hours and couldn't find any helpful posts...

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to show some of your code, it's impossible to say what's wrong without seeing what you've tried this far.

Comment: And show us the precise error message.

Answer (score 2):

If Xcode sends you a "expected declaration" error message, you probably located Alamofire part in class declaration area.

**Solution:**
Move Alamofire part inside some method. like *viewDidLoad* method.

**Example:**

```
class MyView : UIViewController {

    // Not here 
    // Alamofire.request( ... 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Here
        Alamofire.request( ... 
    }
}
```